# Spacemacs/Evil backward delete from line end

Tags: spacemacs, evil-mode

In Vim if I need to change the last word in line (ex. word "bar") when cursor is at the end (char "r"):

```
    foo bar<cursor>
    nextLine
```

I type `lcb' and get:

```
    foo <cursor>
    nextLine
```

But in Spacemacs after `lcb` (I have `(setq-default evil-cross-lines t)`
in config so `l` doesn't stop at the line end) the linebreak char is deleted too and I get:

```
    foo <cursor>nextLine
```

Is there any option in Evil to get the Vim behaviour?

Comment: wouldn't ``ciw`` work in your case?

Comment: Only for one word. The problem is the same for any backward change/delete: <EOL> is deleted unlike in Vim.